# Inconsistency in AWS Lightsail Distribution Custom Domains www/non-www treatment and some domains don't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have scoured the Internet for this after reading AWS's extremely lacking documentation on the subject (it's coverage of adding domain names is saying "Add each domain name that you will be using" and not anymore specific than that)

First what I'm looking for is a specific, detailed, explanation of Lightsail distribution custom domains for SSL.

First question: Do you put the domains in there with or without www prefix?
Second question: Does the certificate handle BOTH www/non-www or only whatever you put in the box?

Here's what I have.. I have a certificate with 4 domains.. All put in with www in front. One of the domains works in both www and non-www. The other two domains only work with www subdomain, and the last domain doesn't work AT ALL.

When I revert to the old certificate where ALL domains are put in without the www prefix, except the one that does work with both, ALL domains with without the www prefix, none work with the WWW prefix EXCEPT that one that works with both.

ALL domains have their setup like this:

```
@.domain.com A (Distribution selected via dropdown)
www.domain.com CNAME domain.com
```

The two domains that work with WWW but not with the bare domain when I have the certificate with all domains written with www prefix are hosted on Route53, because lovely Lightsail only allows 3 zones. The one that doesn't work AT ALL when written with the www prefix in the certificate is a Lightsail DNS zone. The one that works with both www/non-www when I write the custom domains in the certificate with www prefix, is also a Lightsail DNS zone.

With a complete lack of thorough documentation on how all this works I'm at a loss here. That's why if I at least knew how it works .. FULL DISCLOSURE.. LEAVING NOTHING OUT. then I may be able to figure it out.

If I have to put both www and non-www domains as separate domains in the custom domains certificate, then so be it. It really takes up the 9 domain limit quick but.. oh well.

I tried to figure out if I can use CloudFront instead of LS distribution like how I use Route 53 for extra zones but it seems CloudFront requires a load balancer which costs significant $$$ in both Lightsail and regular AWS, which I'm trying to keep costs to a minimum.

Just to reiterate for those who might find what I wrote above confusing...

New cert - all domains typed with www prefix:

```
Domain A works with WWW, cannot connect to server with root domain
Domain B works with WWW, cannot connect to server with root domain
Domain C works with both WWW and root domain just fine, despite being typed into the cert only with the WWW prefix.
Domain D doesn't work AT ALL. Gets cannot connect to server whether typing with or without www.prefix.
```

Old cert - all domains typed in without www prefix except domain C, which is typed with WWW prefix as a test:

```
Domain C works with both www and root domain just fine. Root domain forwards to www prefix domain.
Domain A works without www prefix. Does not work with www prefix.
Domain B works without www prefix. Does not work with www prefix.
Domain D works without www prefix. Does not work with www prefix.
```

Domains A and B are hosted on Route53. C and D are hosted on Lightsail DNS zones. Domain D is a Wordpress site. Just FYI.